# How do you set the NewRelic AppName using an Azure Cloud Service Project Setting

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, newrelic

I've developed an ASP.net MVC website that is published to Azure using Cloud Services. I publish this website to two separate cloud services, once for staging and once as the live site. I've integrated NewRelic using the Azure Management Portal and nuget package. The problem is that both of these sites are logging to the same NewRelic instance when I'd like to be able to identify them by their own individual apps in NewRelic. Since both sites use the same web.config I'd like to be able to specify the app name in the Cloud Service Project Settings - so that I can set a different app name for each deployment. The nearest I've found is [this NewRelic help page](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/azure-web-sites#key_values) which shows that some properties can be set using Azure settings, but I can't see AppName amongst them.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to set NewRelic.AppName through the Azure management portal settings for the website itself.  This would be a useful feature so you might contact New Relic and submit a feature request.

As you mentioned, separate monitored app instances will aggregate if they use the same New Relic app name.  To differentiate them, you need to specify unique NewRelic.AppName values.  When using the same web.config file for both websites, you can set up separate Visual Studio publishing profiles as described here:

http://www.bradygaster.com/managing-multiple-windows-azure-web-site-environments-using-visual-studio-publishing-profiles

Then use config transforms to adjust NewRelic.AppName for each publishing profile.  Here's an example of the transform in the `<configuration>` element in one of the transformed files:

```
<add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="My Website - Staging"

     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Comment: Thanks that's worked perfectly. I actually used [this article](http://www.macaw.nl/weblog/2013/8/setting-up-website-deployment-to-windows-azure) in the end to set up the web.config transform files to work with my Cloud Service project.